# Frequency Density Graph using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, frequency

I have a pandas data frame created as shown below

```
df_hist2 = pd.DataFrame({'Score':np.random.uniform(0,1,4300)}).append(
    pd.DataFrame({'Score':np.random.uniform(1,3,6900)}),ignore_index=True).append(
    pd.DataFrame({'Score':np.random.uniform(3,5,4900)}),ignore_index=True).append(
    pd.DataFrame({'Score':np.random.uniform(5,10,2000)}),ignore_index=True).append(
    pd.DataFrame({'Score':np.random.uniform(10,24,2100)}),ignore_index=True);
```

And I can create a histogram from it as shown below

```
df_hist2.plot.hist(bins=[0,1,3,5,10,24], edgecolor='black', linewidth=1.2)
```

And it is something like this

[image]

However, I want to create a histogram that shows the frequency density instead of just the frequencies where

Frequency Density = Frequency / Width of the bin

I can possibly plot a bar graph where I can create a category for each of the bins ('0-1', '1-3', etc.) and the calculate the densities manually. However, is there a more elegant and easy way to do this?

Moreover, doing it the bar graph way would require me to first calculate the frequencies from the data as well. (in this case I know since I am generating the data manually, but wouldn't know in case of real data)

What I would want is to have something that calculates and plots the following

```
Hours   | Frequency | Width | Density       |
--------------------------------------------|
0 - 1   | 4300      | 1     | 4300/1 = 4300 |
1 - 3   | 6900      | 2     | 6900/2 = 3450 |
3 - 5   | 4900      | 2     | 4900/2 = 2450 |
5 - 10  | 2000      | 5     | 2000/5 = 400  |
10 - 24 | 2100      | 14    | 2100/14 = 150 |
```

And a plot that looks similar to the following (done in excel with some manual editing)

Note: The width of the interval/bin is preserved. The height is changed to reflect the frequency.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that may get you near what you want using the histogram parameter `normed=1`, which gives you the desired histogram shape. Scaling the heights of the histogram using `matplotlib.pyplot as plt` then gives you what you want:

```
fig = df_hist2.plot.hist(bins=[0,1,3,5,10,24], edgecolor='black', linewidth=1.2,
                   normed=True) 
plt.yticks(fig.get_yticks(), [int(x) for x in fig.get_yticks() * len(df_hist2)])
```

You can further customize the exact values of the y ticks to your liking.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! One small update (after I ran the suggested code): The normed parameter is now deprecated and is replaced by density parameter. Cheers !